# How to bring products from opportunity to quotation

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

Hello I am new to odoo and want some help.

I have created a tab products(many2many) in opportunity (your pipeline) which  contains product which comes from mass mailing which has been customized. Now when a opportunity is won and converted into an quotation i want those products present in opportunity to be transferred in order_line(one2many) tab of quotation.
   I need to know is there any possible way to complete this functionality.

Comment: i have extracted the products id from many2many field of your pipeline and in create method of sale order i have written them...but nothing is happening.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways, how to do that:

**Lead (Opportunity) scope**

Try to override the functionality of Odoo which is creating the `sale.order` from `crm.lead`. Here you have to create `sale.order.line` via one2many triplets ([look into write method](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#module-openerp.api)) or after `sale.order` creation, create some `sale.order.line` by yourself (with values and create())

**Order scope (only useful when you have the lead ID on sale.order creation)**

Get the `crm.lead` (when provided) and create `sale.order.line` by one of the approaches from "Lead (Opportunity) scope".